# How to convert an array to object in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

[image: I want the format like this, in one array there are several objects]

[image: but the result is like this, in the array there is an array]

my code from folder in App\Reports\ExportReport.php

```
class ReportExport implements FromCollection
{
public function collection()
    {
      $location_library = \App\Models\LocationLibrary::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->get();
      foreach ($location_library as $key => $locations) {
                $cross_kehadiran[] = DB::table('attendance as in')
                        ->where('in.in_out', 'in')
                        ->where('in.attendance_location_id', $locations->id)
                        ->where('in.company_id', '!=', \Session::get('selected_company'))
                        ->whereDate('in.created', Carbon::today())
                        ->leftJoin('attendance as out', function ($join) {
                            $join->on('in.employee_id', 'out.employee_id')
                                ->where('out.in_out', 'out')
                                ->where('out.attendance_location_id', 'in.attendance_location_id')
                                ->whereDate('out.created', Carbon::today());
                        })
                        ->join('employee', 'employee.id', 'in.employee_id')
                        ->join('location_library', 'location_library.id',     'in.attendance_location_id')
                        ->join('company as cp', 'cp.id', 'in.company_id')
                        ->join('employee_in_app as e_app', 'e_app.employee_id', 'in.employee_id')
                        ->select('employee.name', 'cp.alias', 'in.employee_id','location_library.location_name',  DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(in.attendance_time, "%H:%i:%s") as in_time'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(out.attendance_time, "%H:%i:%s") as out_time'), 'e_app.note')
                        ->orderBy('in.attendance_time', 'DESC')
                        ->get();
       }

     $object = (object) $cross_kehadiran;

     dd($object);
   }
 }
```

I want the resulting format to be like image number one but the result I get is number two. I want to convert an array into an object. is there a way to solve my problem? help me, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I want the result to be like the first image, in one array there are several objects

Answer (score 0):

> I also had this issue, but I noticed that json_decode converts JSON array to object.

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($cross_kehadiran));
```

Comment: I have tried this method, but the format is still an array in an array, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

This function will return an object.

```
function getObjectToArray($object)
{
   return @json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but I get an error "Call to a member function all() on array"

Comment: It has been used in many cases and its return responds well. can you show me the response to your data?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `$cross_kehadiran[]` instead of `$cross_kehadiran`. Just try this one and you get array of objects:

```
    $cross_kehadiran[] = DB::table('attendance as in')
                            ->where('in.in_out', 'in')
                            ->where('in.attendance_location_id', $locations->id)
                            ->where('in.company_id', '!=', \Session::get('selected_company'))
                            ->whereDate('in.created', Carbon::today())
                            ->leftJoin('attendance as out', function ($join) {
                                $join->on('in.employee_id', 'out.employee_id')
                                    ->where('out.in_out', 'out')
                                    ->where('out.attendance_location_id', 'in.attendance_location_id')
                                    ->whereDate('out.created', Carbon::today());
                            })
                            ->join('employee', 'employee.id', 'in.employee_id')
                            ->join('location_library', 'location_library.id', 'in.attendance_location_id')
                            ->join('company as cp', 'cp.id', 'in.company_id')
                            ->join('employee_in_app as e_app', 'e_app.employee_id', 'in.employee_id')
                            ->select('employee.name', 'cp.alias', 'in.employee_id','location_library.location_name',  DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(in.attendance_time, "%H:%i:%s") as in_time'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(out.attendance_time, "%H:%i:%s") as out_time'), 'e_app.note')
                            ->orderBy('in.attendance_time', 'DESC')
                            ->get();
        
dd($object);
```

Comment: i use `$cross_kehadiran[]` because i get that data in foreach

Answer (score 0):

For multi-dimentional arrays

```
static public function array_to_object(array $array)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                $array[$key] = self::array_to_object($value);
            }
        }
        return (object)$array;
    }
```